# will mysql lock all table while processing

Tags: mysql, database, locking, innodb

As we all know, row(record) lock are supported in Innodb engine.
There is no doubt that the following sql is atomic and in a transaction.

```
update tableA t 
set t.oneField = someValue 
where t.primaryKey = id
```

But I am confused at the following situation(**without where condition**)

```
update tableA t 
set t.oneField = someValue
```

What I want to ask is, will mysql lock the entire table while executing this sql?
More specific, **when rowA has been processed and mysql is processing other rows, is rowA still locked while this sql is still processing**? 
Any tool or sql command could use to know whether rowB is locked or not?

I have read doc https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking.html but still confused.

More over, if it is possible, could you give me a specific case or demo or experiment to illustrate your conclusion. Something that I could do it myself both ok.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what about the situation，update tableA t 
set t.oneField = someValue where t.primaryKey in (1, 2, ……)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying that does not "lock the table" is being *technically* correct.  In reality, it "locks every row".  To the user these feel the same.

Both of your two queries will try to run, but they will soon interfere with each other.  *Probably* one will delay until the other finishes.  In *some* situations, a "deadlock" will be detected and one query will be aborted.  (You must test for errors.)

The important distinction with the predecessor (`ENGINE=MyISAM`) is that all operations "locked the table".  Updating one row could not start until a separate thread, which was updating a different row, finished.  And, the interference between `UPDATE` and `SELECT` was greater.

With InnoDB, updates of separate rows can happen simultaneously, and selects can also be going on while the updates are happening.

Comment: **With InnoDB, updates of separate rows can happen simultaneously, and selects can also be going on while the updates are happening**. So it means the the innodb will not lock the rows it has processed while the sql is still executing no matter the sql has where condition or not right ?

Comment: @jingb - Yes, that is a good summary.  But I hesitate to say "absolutely, positively, 100%" -- because there are rare, contorted, obscure, edge-cases that can cause slightly different things to happen.  So, check for errors.  InnoDB performs things "optimistically" -- Conflicts are rare; InnoDB can transparently handle most of them; a few are fixed by delaying one thread (again transparently); but sometimes deadlocks can happen.